# Resultant property for Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have seen plenty of proofs that $\textrm{Res}(f,g) = 0$ iff $f$ and $g$ have a common factor not constant. But every time it's assumed that $f$ and $g$ are polynomials over some algebraic closed field. In this case we can just work with their roots and the result comes easily.

I'm trying to show that this result is also valid for Integral Domains. I managed to prove the first implication "$\textrm{Res}(f,g) = 0 \implies f,g$ have common factor not constant", but the second one is not coming. I need some help here, thanks.

PS: $\textrm{Res}(f,g)$ is the resultant of $f$ and $g$, I'm using the determinant definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let in the following $A$ be the integral domain and $K$ its quotient field.

It is convenient to remember that the determinantal criterion of $R(f,g) = 0$ is equivalent to the existence of $g_1, f_1 \in K[X]$ with $\deg g_1 < \deg g$ and $\deg f_1 < \deg f$ so that

$$f g_1 = g f_1$$

in $K[X]$

So if $R(f,g) = 0$ and $f$ and $g$ have no common factor then $g$ would be a divisor of $g_1$ and $f$ a divisor of $f_1$ which is impossible by degree cause.

The other way round, let $f = f_2 h$ and $g = g_2 h$ in $A[X]$ share a common factor $h \in A[X]$. Then obviously $f g_2 = g f_2$ with $\deg g_2 < \deg g$ and $\deg f_2 < \deg f$. So by the abovementioned equivalence $R(f,g) = 0$.

Comment: Did you use the quotient field because of $g_1$ and $f_1$ ?

Comment: Yes, I embedded the matrix $A_{f,g}$ from $A^{n \times n}$ to $K^{n \times n}$ to be able to use standard linear algebra theorems on its null-space. Additionally $K[X]$ is a UFD which is not necessarily the case with $A[X]$.